# retrieve records from a db without the same id

Tags: php, mysql

.what i want to do is to retrieve records from my database and display everything but the condition is not to display all records having the same task_id but to display only the newest among them. how do I select the newest among the records with the same task_id?

Comment: Please share your table definition which helps us give you a query or point you to a right direction. Also, gives us what have you tried too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a column like

```
last_modified TIMESTAMP
```

so each time a row is inserted, or updated, the `last_modified` column gets updated with the current timestamp. Then, all you need is a query like

```
SELECT *
  FROM tblTask
 WHERE task_id = n
 ORDER BY last_modified DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

Will fetch the latest 5 updated tasks from the database with the given `task_id`. Remove the `WHERE` clause to get the newest tasks regardless of the `task_id`.

**note**: the `TIMESTAMP` data type is special, in the sense that MySQL will update the field automatically, by default, to the current timestamp, unless a value is explicitly defined in the insert or update query. If this behavior is not wanted, use `DATETIME`, but it will require that you specify the column value for the new column (unless a default value is set in the table)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a date field (actually timestamp) in your database u can use `group by` and `order by` to do the job:

`SELECT * 
FROM TBL
GROUP BY task_id
ORDER BY date DESC`

Comment: The above query won't give right results because the GROUP BY will always pick the first task_id record that may not necessarily be the newest one. For example, assume the table has these entries:

task_id | time\n
1       | 2011-06-16 11:05:10
2       | 2011-06-16 12:11:46
1       | 2011-06-16 12:50:29

Now, the result after the GROUP BY:

1       | 2011-06-16 11:05:10
2       | 2011-06-16 12:11:46

Even after the ORDER BY, it won't give you the desired result because it will only sort the above records. But is desired is "2011-06-16 12:5-0:29" for task_id = 1

Comment: Sorry for the mess in my above comment but I couldn't help with the formatting

Answer (score 0):

For MYSQL TIMESTAMP it is good practice to specify the default and on update action

```
last_modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 0):

@rahim asgari

If you want to list only the tasks having more than one record ,then

SELECT * FROM TBL GROUP BY task_id HAVING count(task_id)>1 ORDER BY date DESC

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM `your_table`
    ORDER BY `task_time` DESC
) `TT`
GROUP BY `TT`.`task_id`;
```

Please note to change in the above query, `your_table` with your table name and `task_id`, `task_time` with your respective ID and time columns.

Also, please note that the above query might run slow if the table has many, many entries, say a million rows.

Let me know if above is the query you were willing to ask.